# How can we implement efficiently a maximum set coverage arc of fixed cardinality?

Tags: graph-algorithm

I am working on solving the following problem and implement the solution in C++.

Let us assume that we have an oriented weighted graph G = (V, A, w) and P a set of persons.

We receive a number of queries such that every query gives a person p and two vertices s and d and asks to compute the minimum weighted path between s and d for the person p. One person can have multiple paths.

After the end of all queries I have a number k <= |A| and I should give k arcs such that the number of persons using at least one of the k arcs is maximal (this is a maximum coverage problem).

To solve the first part I implemented the Djikistra algorithm using priority_queue and I compute the minimal weight between s and d. (Is this a good way to do ?)

To solve the second part I store for every arc the set of persons that use this arc and I use a greedy algorithm to compute the set of arcs (at each stage, I choose an arc used by the largest number of uncovered persons). (Is this a good way to do it ?)

Finally, if my algorithms are goods how can I implement them efficiently in C++?

Comment: Please read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and correct your formatting.  Remember, `$` is not used for in-line code formatting on this forum.

Comment: Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: This might be a better fit for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @timgeb ok do you know how can I migrate it automatically?